# Are functions infinite dimensional vectors?

Tags: functions, reference-request, vector-spaces

> Are functions infinite dimensional vectors?

There are a few sources on the internet that makes this claim, but they do not cite any sources which makes me feel like they are just using it as an analogy.

Is $f(x) = x^2$ a vector?

If so, please provide one legitimate source from the kind like Hilbert, Erdos, Halmo, Dedekind so I can truly resolve this mystery once and for all

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space)?

Comment: Halmos, perhaps, the others not, too early. But there is no mystery. The usual spaces of functions, say to the reals, have a natural vector space structure.

Comment: Is old math the only correct math? Or is it just because they're famous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of functions from a domain $X$ to a field $R$ form a vector space of dimension $|X|$ over $R$. If $X$ is infinite then the vector space is infinite dimensional. The usual spaces $L^p(X,\mu)$ are, however, defined slightly differently, by taking equivalence classes of functions equal up to measure zero (and, of course, having finite $L^p$ norm under $\mu$). Even in this case the end result is a vector space, infinite dimensional under some mild constraints.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space), although the $L^p$ spaces are supposedly named after Lebesgue, they appear earlier in work of F. Riesz. You can check the original paper to see whether the concept of "vector space" is being used.